# Run application connect to SQL Server by Windows Guest user account

Tags: .net, windows, sql-server-2008, clickonce

I have a .NET windows application connected to a SQL Server 2008 database, I am deploying this app on clients machines using click-once technique through the web.

Now I am testing the application under different user permissions.

When I test the application on Administrator user and the standard user (limited user in Windows XP). and the app run successfully

When I tested the application on the Guest user account, I got the following .NET SQL Exception:

```
The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.
 9/26/2012 11:25:33 AM: Stack:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor()
 at    
  System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Initialize
 (IData 
 Services dataServices, Object connection)
 at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.Init(Object connection, MappingSource mapping)
 at System.Data.Linq.DataContext..ctor(String fileOrServerOrConnection, MappingSource 
 mapping)
```

and here is the inner exception:

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters' threw an exception. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'Global.net data provider for sqlserver' is denied.
   at System.IO._*Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.Threading.Mutex.<>c*_DisplayClass3.<.ctor>b__0(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.Mutex..ctor(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name, Boolean& createdNew, MutexSecurity mutexSecurity)
   at System.Diagnostics.SharedUtils.EnterMutexWithoutGlobal(String mutexName, Mutex& mutex)
   at System.Diagnostics.SharedPerformanceCounter.Verify(CategoryEntry* currentCategoryPointer)
   at System.Diagnostics.SharedPerformanceCounter.FindCategory(CategoryEntry** returnCategoryPointerReference)
   at System.Diagnostics.SharedPerformanceCounter.GetCounter(String counterName, String instanceName, Boolean enableReuse, PerformanceCounterInstanceLifetime lifetime)
   at System.Diagnostics.SharedPerformanceCounter..ctor(String catName, String counterName, String instanceName, PerformanceCounterInstanceLifetime lifetime)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.Initialize()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.set_RawValue(Int64 value)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolCounters.Counter..ctor(String categoryName, String instanceName, String counterName, PerformanceCounterType counterType)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolCounters..ctor(String categoryName, String categoryHelp)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters..ctor()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory..ctor()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..cctor()

Can any one tell me how to solve this problem? :)

Comment: It would be interesting to see whether that exception has an `InnerException`. Chasing through the chain of class constructors, the only likely suspect I can see related to performance counters.

Comment: *Edit* your question - don't try to put complex items (requiring formatting) in comments.

Comment: i have added the inner exception to the question body :)

Answer (score 0):

Via SSMS add the Guest (Security Logins)  then add the account to the specific database Under Sercurity Accounts.